# how to construct a javascript regex to extract a number

Tags: javascript, regex

Extract the number after `#/` from my string: `abcdefg#/123`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes the match will succeed: `'abcdefg#/123'.match(/#\/(\d+)/)[1]`